# Countable union of locally closed sets vs countable union of closed sets

Tags: general-topology

For $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, we can write locally closed sets (intersection of an open and a closed set) as the countable union of closed sets (e.g. $(1,2] = \cup_n[1+1/n,2]$), so countable unions of locally closed sets can be written as countable unions of closed sets.
I was trying to find a counter example for this to always hold, but the argument above seems to work in metric spaces, after which I have no intuition.
Do you know of any (simple) example of a set that is equal to the countable union of locally closed sets, but not the countable union of closed sets?

Comment: I think the cofinite topology on an uncountable set would work. Will write it up properly if no-one has by the time I get home.

Comment: I also think this *is* true for metric spaces, since each open set is a countable union of closed sets. But not sure.

Comment: @BenMillwood: I don't think the co-$\kappa$ topology is going to work for any cardinal $\kappa$, because  I think locally closed and closed are equivalent in such a topology.

Comment: @RobArthan: hmm, we probably differ in some definition. I mean the topology in which a set is open if its complement is finite, in which open sets are locally closed but not closed.

Comment: (this question is the first time I've thought about locally closed sets, so maybe I'm wrong to think any open set is locally closed? but it is surely the intersection of itself and the whole set...)

Comment: @BenMillwood:  We are talking about the same definition. I was forgetting that in the cofinite (say) topology, we also include the whole set as closed, so that any open set counts as locally closed.

Comment: @RobArthan indeed the definition I gave above forgot to include that case too 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since any open set is locally closed, it should be enough to find an open set that isn't the union of countably many closed sets. This is easily satisfied by topologies where all the non-empty open sets are very "large" and all the non-full closed sets are very "small", so that a countable union of them isn't "big enough".

Enter the cofinite topology on an uncountable set X. Any open set has uncountably many points, but a countable union of closed sets (excluding X itself) has at most countably many points. So any non-X open set is an example of a locally closed set that is not a union of countably many closed sets.

Comment: That was a very nice example! Do you know of any that works with arbitrary unions? Also if "metric space -> union of locally closed = union of closed" is true, your example give a really nice proof that the co-finite topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is not metrizable right?

Comment: For arbitrary unions: can't immediately think of anything. Using closed sets that are "too small" doesn't work anymore, since you can just take a big union of them. Also note that in any topology where points are closed, every subset is a union of closed sets. For your latter question, yeah this would prove the cofinite topology on $\mathbb R$ is not metrizable, but there are much easier ways to prove that :) e.g. every pair of non-empty open subsets has non-empty intersection